# Crontab to send dump data to windows machine

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, cron

I have **mysql Database** in Linux machine which should be dumped by using **crontab** and the data directly should have to store in a remote windows system. Is this possible? if yes, how?

Comment: yes it's possible. what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea what to do,first i performed mysql dumps **"mysqldump -u root -p Database_name > New-database_name.sql"** using cron tab in "/home/database_dump" location then i tried to perform SCP by cron no luck!  can you tell me a single script which takes mysql database from Linux and copies to Windows.

Comment: It may not be straightforward as a simple script.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a script similar to the one below.
It would be best if you tested the script before running it from `cron`. 
The scp command will prompt for the user's password on the destination machine - unless the ssh key setup on the scp destination machine contains public key authorization. For this to work with cron the scp command must be able to copy *without user input of a password*.
Once it works then set up the `crontab` entry. Specify the full path of the script in the entry.

```
export DB_DUMP_DIR=/home/database_dump
export DB_NAME=database_name_$(date '+%Y_%m_%d').sql

mysqldump -u root -p database_name > ${DB_DUMP_DIR}/${DB_NAME}
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
    scp ${DB_DUMP_DIR}/${DB_NAME} user@windows_machine:
else
    echo "Error generating database dump"
fi
```

Comment: The Script runs well, But i need a script which the Mysql-dump should be named as per the current date and should be backed up daily to the remote system(Windows Machine) in D:\Database_backup.

Comment: The script should save the files in Windows machine "D:\Database_backup" as **db_7/27/2013.sql, db_7/28/2013.sql, db_7/29/2013.sql** etc...

Comment: Have you managed to copy files from linux to windows at all so far?

Comment: yes i did it, last step is to make ssh public key authorization and setup cron that's it.

Comment: How can i ssh public key authorization for windows as server and Linux as client i use cygwin in windows, reverse is possible but stuck with windows public key authorization.

Comment: cygwin - good, that should make it fairly easy. Take a look at this: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/

Comment: I had configured SSH but what my query was i copied **id_rsa.pub** key of my server into windows client machine **"C:\cygwin\home\user\.ssh"** and renamed it as authorized_keys with .txt extension and just checked from the server it again prompts for password??? do i need to copy the RSA key of server into cygwin's etc?

Comment: Is there an alternative that i can write the password in the script and make the script permission as 600?

Comment: Is there any file transfer protocol which doesn't prompts for a password, the password should be provided in the script and automated, i tried with **cygwin** but it doesn't works.